# Heroku + Clojure (webnoir), how to do lein clean?

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen, cloud9-ide, noir

I'm hosting a webnoir site on heroku and after renaming a namespace and file, I'm getting the following error in the log:

> Warning: *coercions* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically
>   rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate
>   ^:dynamic *coercions* or change the name.

I found something online that said I should try a `lein clean` command.  Does anyone know how to achieve this? The Heroku help didn't indicate a command for this.

I'm using cloud9 as my ide / heroku integration if there is something I can do via that. Otherwise I have the heroku toolbelt too.

Answer (score 2):

This error probably isn't an issue: It's because a name surrounded in asterisks like `*coercions*` is expected to be dynamic, but doesn't have the `^:dynamic` metadata tag that is needed if you you want to re-bind it dynamically.

Unless you actually want to dynamically re-bind it, there won't be any problem.

Since it's a compiler warning, I don't think `lein clean` will make any difference - you'll get the same warning regardless of whether you use a clean build or not.